How to Use a Dynamic Connection String During SSIS Package Validation in Visual Studio 2017 Package Deployment Model?
Is there any event handler or task that can dynamically change the connection during the validation phase of a package when executed through the Execute Package utility?
I have two variables in my configuration file, DriverName1 and DriverName2. I want the connections to be updated during the validation phase itself so that the package does not give errors due to missing connections or drivers at validation time.
I do not want to set DelayValidation = True.
I need an option that will ensure the task passes validation. I have searched Google but couldn't find anything related.
I want everything to work correctly during package validation as well. I have already implemented code to change the connection string at runtime, but it is not working during validation.

Please give me an answer as soon as possible.
